# How to create heat haze effect in Libgdx?

Tags: shaders, libgdx, post-processing

I would like to create a heat haze effect for a 2D game I am making.

Do You have ideas or suggestions, how to get that effect. I am using Libgdx(OpenGL 2.0).

Thank You in advance!

Comment: You should post a picture or screenshot demonstrating the effect.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.SE.  This site generally discourages "how-to" questions, and instead prefers questions with specific technical or design problems.  If you are interested in learning how to proceed, what to study, or for advice, you should try visiting [chat].  But...I just realized that will be difficult for you, since you don't have the requisite 20 reputation.

Comment: Ok, try reading this: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/OpenGLShader  What you want is to distort your game screen in some kind of wavy pattern.  That could be accomplished with a fragment shader as part of a [post-processing](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-processing) system.  Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I used this solution to make a water distortion effect. You could use the sin waves vertically instead of horizontally to possibly achieve your effect. I draw what might get distorted onto a `FrameBuffer`. I make regions of the buffer texture that will be redrawn with a distortion shader applied. 
**GdxGame.java**

```
void create(){
    scaleX =  Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / gs.cam.viewportWidth ; //floats that convert the width and height in world
    scaleY =   Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / gs.cam.viewportHeight;//to width and height on screen
    //The above floats need to be recalculated on screen resize, and the frame buffer will also need to be recreated
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("data/vertexShader.glsl").readString(),Gdx.files.internal("data/fragmentShader.glsl").readString());
    coords = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    heatRegions = new ArrayList<TextureRegion>();
    heatCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    heatDimensions = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    idt = new Matrix4();
    time = 0f; //makes the effect move over time
    /*This is a bad way to store your regions. I assume some object generates heat waves, 
    so use it's x and y and width and height, also have it store it's own distortionRegion
    instead of storing ArrayLists*/
    //Create a FrameBuffer to draw the objects that will be distorted to. 
    try {//This try-catch block is because some Androids don't support Format.RGBA8888
            frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        }catch (GdxRuntimeException e){ 
            frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        } 

    heatRegions.add(new TextureRegion(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()));
    heatCoords.add(new Vector2(0,0));
    heatDimensions.add(new Vector2(32,32));
}

public void render(){
    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    time += dt ;
    float angle = time * (2 * MathUtils.PI);
    if (angle > (2 * MathUtils.PI))
        angle -= (2 * MathUtils.PI);

    Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);   
    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformf("timedelta", -angle);
    shader.end();

    frameBuffer.begin();    
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    //Draw the objects that will be rendered BEHIND the heat wave to the FrameBuffer so that they will get distorted
    batch.end();
    frameBuffer.end();
    //Draw the buffer to screen
    g.setProjectionMatrix(idt);
    g.begin();
    g.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), -1, 1, 2, -2); //IIRC, you need to vertically flip it. If I remembered wrong, then do -1, -1, 2, 2
    g.end();
    g.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    //Now we will actually use the effect by drawing our heat regions
    batch.setShader(shader);
    batch.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < heatRegions.size(); i++){
        TextureRegion region = heatRegions.get(i); 
        coords.set(heatCoords.get(i).x, heatCoords.get(i).y,0);//
        coords.project(cam.combined); //get screen coordinates for the coords
        region.setTexture(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());
        //cut out the area to distort
        region.setRegion(coords.x, coords.y,
                        heatDimensions.get(i).x * scaleX,heatDimensions.get(i).y * scaleY); 
        //draw it with the distortion shader applied
        batch.draw(region, coords.x, coords.y, 
                        heatDimensions.get(i).x * scaleX,heatDimensions.get(i).y * scaleY);
  }
  batch.end();

}
```

**GLSL Shaders Formatted as Java Strings**

```
public static String waterFragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
        + "precision mediump float;\n"
        + "#endif\n"
        + "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
        + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D u_texture2;\n"
        + "uniform float timedelta;\n"
        + "uniform vec2 sss;\n"
        + "uniform vec2 u_maxclamp;\n"
        + "void main()                                  \n"
        + "{                                            \n"
        + "  vec2 displacement = texture2D(u_texture2, v_texCoords/4.0).xy;\n" //
        + "  float t=v_texCoords.y +displacement.y*0.7-0.15+  (sin(v_texCoords.x * 40.0+timedelta) * 0.003); \n" //swap the x & y stuff here to make the waves vertical instead of horizontal
        + "  gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_texCoords.x,t ));\n"
        + "}";

public static String vertexShader = 
        "attribute vec4 a_position;    \n"
        + "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n"
        + "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n"
        + "varying vec4 v_color;" 
        + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;"
        + "void main()                  \n"
        + "{                            \n"
        + "   v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); \n"
        + "   v_texCoords = a_texCoord0; \n"
        + "   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;  \n"
        + "}";
```